# How can I generalize Either to more (and recursive) types?

Tags: scala, either, type-alias

Scala's `Either[A, B]` type is a type that's either `A` or `B`.

Is there a generalization that lets me define something like the following?

```
type JSON = Either[String, Int, Float, List[JSON], Map[String, JSON]]
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The typical approach would be to use a sealed trait with final subtypes.

```
sealed trait JSON
final case class StringJSON(x: String) extends JSON
final case class IntJSON(x: Int) extends JSON
final case class FloatJSON(x: Float) extends JSON
final case class ListJSON(x: List[JSON]) extends JSON
final case class MapJSON(x: Map[String, JSON]) extends JSON
```

---

The [feature overview of Shapeless](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/wiki/Feature-overview:-shapeless-2.0.0) says

> shapeless has a Coproduct type, a generalization of Scala's `Either` to an arbitrary number of choices.

So my first thought would be to try this...

```
type JSON = String :+: Int :+: Float :+: List[JSON] :+: Map[String, JSON]
```

... but unfortunately the cyclic reference to `JSON` doesn't work. And I think this is the problem you're going to run into with any approach you try.

---

[David Barri](http://japgolly.blogspot.com/2015/02/zero-overhead-recursive-adt-coproducts.html) suggests an approach involving the "cake pattern", though I don't think it's helpful here.

Comment: Still need to admit scalaz has `Either3`, though your answer definitely way to go.

Answer (score 6):

Even if you defined your own `FiveWay` type (an "`Either`" that would take five type parameters), Scala would not allow you to define

```
type Json = FiveWay[String, Int, Float, List[Json], Map[String, Json]]
```

Why? Because a type alias (`Json`, here) cannot appear on the right-hand side of its own definition. 
The following example illustrates this fact:

```
scala> type Json = Either[String, Json]
<console>:11: error: illegal cyclic reference involving type Json
       type Json = Either[String, Json]
```

More precisely, the Scala specification ([section 4.3](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/04-basic-declarations-and-definitions.html#type-declarations-and-type-aliases)) tells us that

> the type `T` in a type alias `type t[tps] = T` may not refer directly or indirectly to the name `t`

What you want to do here, instead, is apply the Algebraic-Data-Type pattern:

```
sealed trait Json

final case class JsonString(string: String) extends Json

final case class JsonInt(int: Int) extends Json

final case class JsonFloat(float: Float) extends Json

final case class JsonArray(list: List[Json]) extends Json

final case class JsonObject(map: Map[String, Json]) extends Json
```